# Jest. supertest and coverage

Tags: jestjs, supertest

I learn NodeJS and stumble upon library jest. For express web framework test, I require a further library called `supertest`. I would like some help to both learn to do it properly and obtain the dreamed 100% coverage on the repository [sappio](https://github.com/web-needle/sappio). For now, I have only 1 (one) test file in folder `core/__test__`. However, it should cover every js file. How should I proceed?

One of my concerns regards coverage: after the command run `npm run test`, the resulting output log does not exhibit the desired uncovered lines. Sad :'(

```
> sappio@1.0.0 test
> jest --collect-coverage --coverage

 PASS  core/__test__/app.test.js
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.841 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: You should at least share your jest configuration file contents. For me to get percentage had to add `coverageProvider: 'v8'` and convert the `collectCoverageFrom` value `**/*.{js}` to `**/*.js`

Comment: In my case just adding coverageProvider: 'v8' worked.